# Python Beautiful soup, select secont value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a Html Code what looks like

```
 <input type="hidden" value="" id="productBsId" />
.
.
.
.
 <input type="hidden" value="61980" id="productBsId" />
```

When I try `sizefund = soup.find('input', {'id': 'productBsId'}).get('value')`

It prints "" instead of "61980". So it selects the first value and prints it. How can I select the second?

Comment: `sizefund = soup.findAll('input', {'id': 'productBsId'})[1].get('value')`

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, you just need to handle elements where the `value` attribute is empty

```
sizefund = soup.find('input', {'id': 'productBsId', 'value': lambda o: o != ''}).get('value')
```

or you can use `findAll` and take the second element

```
sizefund = soup.findAll('input', {'id': 'productBsId'})[1].get('value')
```

Comment: Thanks. `<ul><li class="active">Bitte Größe wählen</li><li class="disabled">
(EU 41 - US 8)                      </li><li class="">
EU 42 - US 8,5                      </li><li class="">
EU 42,5 - US 9                      </li><li class="">
EU 43 - US 9,5                      </li><li class="disabled">
(EU 44 - US 10)                      </li><li class="disabled">
(EU 44,5 - US 10,5)                      </li><li class="disabled">
(EU 45 - US 11)                      </li><li class="">
EU 46 - US 12                      </li></ul>` How can I count the <li> ... </li> output shoul be 8